# How to fix this color event function in Javascript in this Pixel Art Maker?

Tags: javascript, events

I need to know how to clear everything when clicking submit so It will work again without any problems

I created the project and everything is fine when putting width and height and clicking submit(first time) the table created and everything is working and also you can put any color but the problem in click submit (second time) the table created but I can't use colors but when click submit (third time) the colors are working and so How can I clear everything when click the submit each time??  https://codepen.io/mokai2008/pen/OYqzxj

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#sizePicker');

form.addEventListener('submit', formSubmit);

function formSubmit() {
  event.preventDefault();

  const width = document.querySelector('#inputWidth').value;
  const height = document.querySelector('#inputHeight').value;

  makeGrid(width, height);


}

function makeGrid(width, height) {


// Select Width , Height and color values

  const table = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');

// Create the Canvas
  let grid = '';

  for(let i = 1; i <= width; i++) {
    grid += `<tr>`
    for(let j = 1; j <= height; j++) {
      grid += `<td class='cell'></td>`;
    }
    grid += `</tr>`;
  }

  table.innerHTML = grid;

  //call the color function
addColor();

}
  // Create event listener for the color

function addColor() {
  const color = document.querySelector('#colorPicker').value;

  document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains('cell')) {
      const event = e.target;
      console.log('berfore ask', e.target);
      if(event.hasAttribute('style')) {
        console.log('there is style attr to remove', e.target);

        event.removeAttribute('style');

      } else {
        console.log('there is no att so we create it', e.target);

        event.style.backgroundColor = color;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for every submit you add a new listener without removing the old one. So the first time it work the way you want. The second time it has 2 listeners and on click it first adds the color and on the second event listener it removes it. Now for if we continue with submitting it will always cancel out when it is an even number of listeners. If the listener number is odd it will behave like it is supposed to do.

this is what i would do(with minimal changes to your code)

```
// Select color input


// Select size input

// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()

const form = document.querySelector('#sizePicker');

form.addEventListener('submit', formSubmit);
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', eventListener);

function formSubmit() {
  event.preventDefault();

  const width = document.querySelector('#inputWidth').value;
  const height = document.querySelector('#inputHeight').value;

  makeGrid(width, height);


}

function makeGrid(width, height) {


// Select Width , Height and color values

  const table = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');

// Create the Canvas
  let grid = '';

  for(let i = 1; i <= width; i++) {
    grid += `<tr>`
    for(let j = 1; j <= height; j++) {
      grid += `<td class='cell'></td>`;
    }
    grid += `</tr>`;
  }

  table.innerHTML = grid;
}
  // Create event listener for the color


function eventListener(e) {
  const color = document.querySelector('#colorPicker').value;
    if(e.target.classList.contains('cell')) {
      const event = e.target;
      console.log('berfore ask', e.target);
      if(event.hasAttribute('style')) {
        console.log('there is style attr to remove', e.target);

        event.removeAttribute('style');

      } else {
        console.log('there is no att so we create it', e.target);

        event.style.backgroundColor = color;
      }
    }
  }
```

Not only it would solve your problem, but it would allow to change the color from colorpicker even after the onSubmit was executed.

The reason this works is that you are changing only the content of table element and not destroying it. So the listener is still there even though the content is changed.